# Unsupported combination of input and output array formats in function 'cv::reduce'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I try use `cv.reduce` function do something work, but it's always throw errors no matter how I change `dtype`, Can someone know the reason?
[image]

Comment: Does this help cv2.reduce(R1, 1, cv2.REDUCE_SMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for arrays with negative values

Comment: @JeruLuke I don't know why `opencv`  design it that negative-value not work . `pandas`  can do  this in a similar way without problem.